# How to pass a value of class from view to controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can retrieve a string in this but when I try retrieving a class I'm having an exception error.

```
Customer = new Customer()
{

    FirstName = Request.Form["FirstName"],
    LastName = Request.Form["LastName "],
    BillingAddress = new Address
    {
        StreetAddress1 = Request.Form["StreetAddress1"],

    }
```

I already tried setting a value, it saves successfully, but when I'm getting the data from the value exception error occurs.By the way I'm using a model from the SDK. Thank you

View form

```
@model WebApplication16.Model.ParentModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ParentModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          </div>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditCard.ExpirationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCard.ExpirationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreditCard.ExpirationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditCard.Issuer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCard.Issuer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreditCard.Issuer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.Cvv, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Payment.Cvv, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.Cvv, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>






            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
}

 <div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using Request.Form ? You can use Html helper controls. What is the exception?

Comment: please read the baiscs of asp.net mvc first

Comment: it's getting a null value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't send complex datatypes in a form.

For your given example, you can just send "StreetAddress1" as a string (alongside with "FirstName" and "LastName") and build the Customer object in your controller.

Code for your view:

```
@model Customer

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BillingAddress)<br />
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    }
</div>
```

If you follow this approach, MVC already serializes the Customer object for you:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(Customer c)
{
    string FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName
}
```

Comment: when I debug it, it still don't have value,

Comment: What exactly does not have a value?

Comment: The first name and the lastname

Comment: Can you show me the code you are using in your view now?

Comment: Okay I will add it in my question

Comment: I see several possible issues. 1. What is `WebApplication16.Model.ParentModel`? Does this model have the fields "FirstName" and "LastName"? 2. Where you begin your form (@using (Html.BeginForm())) you should specify the controller and action, which the form is supposed to post to.

Comment: Hi thank you, I already figure it out, thanks to you. because I created a parent model that will merge the 3 model of the sdk model, My customer model should be Parentmodel.Customer. Thank you so much.. great help

Comment: My problem now is the enum type and the int

Comment: Please open a new question for that, as it gets really messy with so many comments to an answer

Comment: Here is my question      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790194/how-to-convert-the-enum-value-to-string-from-view-to-a-controller-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Use `FormCollection` Class in You Controller .. This Will Get You All The Posted Values From Use .. Then u Can Extract Values By Key FromCollection Keys .. Create New Object Based On The Value You Got From The FormCollection , Simply Add a FromCollection Parameter

```
public ActionResult (FormCollection F)
{

}
```

Comment: Maybe Your Are Using Wrong Key To Retrieve The Data ...Inside Your Controller Get The AllKeys Prop Of FormCollection F and Put a Debug Break Point There .. You Will See All The Key Stored In F and Once You Know Your Key's Name You Can Extract Value By Key

Comment: Yes, I already double check the Key to retrieve the data, also try debugging it