# How to convert the ENUM value to String from view to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

So I already know how to get the string,int,decimal and now I'm struggling in this part of enum. How can I convert my enum into a string

```
**Enum statecode = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode.Value;**
Customer = new Customer()
       {
         FirstName = fn,
         LastName = ln,
         BillingAddress = new Address
             {
              StreetAddress1 = street1,
              StreetAddress2 = street2,
              City = city,
              **StateCode = statecode**,
              ZipCode = zipcode
              }
        },
```

so I want to insert the value of this..

```
Enum statecode = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode.Value;
```

to this enum

```
StateCode = statecode,
```

Comment: statecode.ToString() try this.

Comment: I already tried it

Comment: The property `Statecode` (in your object `Address`) is an Enum?

Comment: yes, public Address BillingAddress{get; set;}.. Inside that it have the statecode and everything about the address

Comment: What happens if you just change `Enum` to `string` in the first line? I think, you misunderstood, which part of your program is the Enum.

Comment: string statecode you mean? it became a red line. that saying it cannot convert it to string

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Enum statecode` instead of the type you've defined? To use enums, you must define it first with something like `enum StateCode { MN, CA, NY }`

Comment: What does the tooltip say, which type `apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode.Value` is, when you hover your mouse over the "Value" part?

Comment: I already figure out, it's because of the "Value", so I remove it, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Enum statecode = apsp.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode;
Customer = new Customer()
   {
     FirstName = fn,
     LastName = ln,
     BillingAddress = new Address
         {
          StreetAddress1 = street1,
          StreetAddress2 = street2,
          City = city,
          StateCode = (StateCode)statecode,
          ZipCode = zipcode
          }
    },
```

Answer (score -2):

If .ToString() doesn't work, you can also write your own parser, something like:

```
string EnumToString(Enum myEnum)
{
   switch (myEnum)
   {
      case MyEnumSpecialType :
         return "MyEnumSpecialType";
       //....
      default : 
         return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: all the line is red